# c# SyndicationItem pubdate to GMT

Tags: syndication-feed, georss, syndication-item

I've been trying to produce the an RSS feed using the System.ServiceModel.Syndication library..

At the moment it's displaying AEST with +1000 (e.g. Thu, 23 Apr 2015 09:44:29 +1000) but i need it to be produced as GMT (e.g. Sat, 07 Dec 2013 19:39:04 GMT)

Is there a way to set or force the date format for PublishDate property in the SyndicationItem?  or defaulted to the server time setting ?